# Total derivative for composite functions of matrices

Tags: calculus, matrices

I am wondering if a total derivative for matrices holds as it does in vector calculus (sum over the partial derivatives),
$d u=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} * d x_i$.

For instance, I know that the following holds for matrices given a composite function $g(U) = g(f(X))$,

$\frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial X_{i j}}=\operatorname{Tr}\left[\left(\frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U}\right)^T \frac{\partial U}{\partial X_{i j}}\right] = \frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U} : \frac{\partial U}{\partial X_{i j}}$, where : represents the matrix inner product.

But what about the problem when $g(\sum_i U_i) = g(\sum_i f_i(X))$, i.e. a sum of composite functions?

I am wondering if the following is true, $\frac{dg(U)}{dX} = \sum_i \frac{\partial g(\sum_i U_i)}{\partial U_i} : \frac{d U_i}{d X_{ij}}$? Which would be similar to the total derivative formula for vectors.